# use removeAll() in scheduler task

Tags: typo3, scheduler, extbase

Before doing new stuff, i want my scheduler-Task to remove all entries from the database, the execute-function looks like that:

```
public function execute() {

  $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
  $jobRepository = $objectManager->get('\TYPO3\MyExtension\Domain\Repository\JobRepository');

  //clear DB
  $jobRepository->removeAll();

  (...)//insert new entries to DB

  $objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\PersistenceManagerInterface')->persistAll();

  return true;
}
```

inserting new entries to the DB works fine, but clearing the DB doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `removeAll()` calls `findAll()`:

```
public function removeAll() {
        foreach ($this->findAll() AS $object) {
            $this->remove($object);
        }
    }
```

most likely `findAll()` returns no objects. Did you handle the storage pid? Either disable it or pass it manually. It won't be just there if you use methods of your repository from scheduler context.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Comment: For more Info about setting PID or using Queryset  see answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539156/typo3-repository-findall-not-working.