# removeAll() from repository in scheduler task

Tags: typo3, extbase

For my scheduler task, I want to delete all the existing data from repository before updating it, every time the scheduler runs. I am able to save and add new data from XML File using add().

class FunctionFetcherService {

```
public function fetchRoomandLesson() {
    $path = 'http:abc.dll?type=room&content=xml';
    $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
    $roomRepository = $objectManager->get("School\\booking\\Domain\\Repository\\RoomsRepository");
    $this->roomRepository->removeAll();
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $xmlArray = json_decode($json, true);
    $serialized_array = serialize($xmlArray);
    $unserialized_array = unserialize($serialized_array);
```

An error occurs removeAll() called on Null. I also referred to the already asked question: [use removeAll() in scheduler task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040587/use-removeall-in-scheduler-task) but it does doe not  work.

Comment: $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_TRUNCATEquery('table'); works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You create the repository as variable `$roomRepository` and then try to access it through `$this->roomRepository`. Changing `$this->roomRepository` to `$roomRepository` should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an [Extbase CommandController](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/10-Outlook/3-Command-controllers.html) as your scheduler task. All registered commands are available in the scheduler as well as CLI commands.

By using CommandControllers you can use the full extbase framework, such as dependency injections and validations.

Please note that CommandController command methods must be suffixed with `Command` just like the linked example.

Comment: Btw. I noticed a couple of typos in your method - as Rudy mentioned you're referring to `$this->roomRepository` whereas you instantiate `$roomRepository`.
Also you should take great care to ensure that you adhere to the UpperCamelCase naming convention in extbase, so your repository should be named `School\Booking\Domain\Repository\RoomsRepository`